# How to sample from the prior predictive distribution with the BSTS R package?

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, bsts

Assuming I have to use the [bsts package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/index.html) in `R`, I'm trying to understand the degree to which my prior distribution choices (implicit or otherwise) are consistent with my domain expertise. One intuitive way to do this frequently recommended is via [prior predictive checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution#Prior_vs._posterior_predictive_distribution). Is there a way of obtaining prior-predictive samples from a BSTS model object? The reference manual doesn't seem to have this option directly, but I'm wondering whether there's a hacky way of doing it.

Comment: This would depend on whether regressors are present in your model.. If so, then ```SpikeSlabPrior``` can be used to obtain the prior for the regression component of the model. Otherwise, ```SdPrior``` can be used to obtain the prior on the residual standard deviation. Please see this guide for more details: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/bsts.pdf